# Can user set Slots and Slots synonyms by voice

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

i'v create a skill with intents and uterrance and slots
I would like to know if the user is able to set a slots or slots synonym by voice.

**My settings:**
Intent : OutletIntent
Uterrence : Can you turn on {IOT}
Slots : {IOT} : outlet

**For example:**

> User :Can you turn on the outlet please Alexa : Outlet turned on
>
> User: Can you add synonym of outlet  Alexa: tell me the synonym User:
>   Power Alexa: Done
>
> User: Can you turn on the Power please Alexa: Power turned on

And then

Slots -> {IOT} : outlet => synonyms : Power

Hop it's clear, if not don't hesitate to tell me haha,
Thanks by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot change the interaction model of a skill as one of it's user.**
As a developer you can always add new synonyms via the developer portal or via Alexa Skill Management API. But for each change you make in the interaction model requires your skill to be re-built.

Changes in interaction model is only possible in `development skills` (via portal or SMAPI), once your skill is published you will never be able to add a synonym. If you want to add, then its an interaction model change and you will have to get certified before you publish that new skill version (technically new/updated interaction model).

---

> When you create a custom slot type, a key concept to understand is
>   that this is training data for Alexa’s NLP (natural language
>   processing). The values you provide are NOT a strict enum or array
>   that limit what the user can say. This has two implications
>
> 1) words and phrases not in your slot values will be passed to you,
>
> 2) your code needs to perform any validation you require if what’s
>   said is unknown

So you can expect Alexa to return slot values that are not defined in examples. Your `IOT` slot will return other values too. Just give a wide variety of examples slot values for `IOT`. Whenever your skill's backend receives a slot value just validate it and proceed.

If you want to only respond to user added synonyms, you can save the new slot value when the user adds it.
Ex:

```
User: Can you add synonym of outlet
Alexa: tell me the synonym 
User: Power
```

Now when you receive this slot value as power, persist it against the list of synonyms added by the user for outlet in a database. ie, {IOT} slot.

```
Alexa: Done
```

Now when the user says:

```
User: Can you turn on the Power please
```

Since Alexa passes other non defined slot values, you should get `IOT` slot value as `power`. Now in your backend check whether value `power` is already added as synonym for `outlet` and respond accordingly.

**For a published skill any change in interaction model requires it be certified before the new version is live again.**

Comment: Thanks everything is clearest for me now.

So if i understand, the only solution is to use a external database that will save synonym ? And Alexa isn't able to learn from the user voice ?
I'm sorry, i'm a Alexa beginner haha

Thanks again for your answer, very helpfull and clear !

Comment: Alexa will pick up slot values based on the examples that you gave before you built the skill. As I said, if you want to restrict users to  synonyms set by the user, persist it in a database (when the user sets it) and validate (when the user use the newly set synonym).

Comment: SMAPI is useful in a different ways. You can use it automate skill generation. You can use it to automate promotion of dev skills to test skills (if you are using two separate skills for testing and development). You can use it wherever an API is helpful.

Comment: Okay, thanks to taken time to answer me for that question :)

Comment: @CicilThomas I know that it's not advisable to call SMAPI from lambda code. But my solution below is a workaround if one still wants to achieve that. Give me a reason why my solution will not work. It's just a matter of calling an API from lambda with appropriate token.

Comment: @Akshay Milmile It's not about Lambda or tokens. It's fact that any change in interaction model, will require your skill to go through certification process. Which also means if a user add a synonym by your method, the skill needs to be re submitted and get certified before that synonym is actually added to the live skill. Please read my answer, you will understand.

Comment: @CicilThomas but you can do that too with SMAPI. Here -> https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-certification-operations.html#request I have updated my answer to add that

Comment: You can pretty much control every workflow of your skill development with SMAPI. My point is instead of saying that this is just plain impossible, it is achievable at the same time, yes discouraged.

Comment: @AkshayMilmile I know what SMAPI can do. Imagine there are some 5 users for the skill, each of them add a synonym everyday. Your skill will be submitted 5 times everyday for certification. Do you think this is good idea?  Within days 
 your interaction model will be cluttered with synonyms of various kind. It will even have synonyms which some users or the developer itself doesn't want.  Yes it is possible, but its a pretty bad idea both from a design perspective and a user perspective.

Comment: I totally agree your point, that's why I added 'discouraged' in my earlier comment. But persisting synonym in database won't allow us to take full advantage of Alexa's natural language understanding and processing capabilities. What I can agree on is if this skill is being used for personal use then I think adding it to the interaction model is preferred. And for the use case you mentioned, where many more users are interacting and exploiting this added functionality of adding synonyms, your option can be preferred.

Comment: My answer suggest to make use of Alexa's natural language processing by adding wide variety of slot values as examples/training-data and not by updating interaction model for every new synonym. The idea to persist synonyms in a database is to validate whether a user has actually added it, if it all a validation is required.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

You need to create intents which could be like below:

Intent: `AskForSynonymChange`
Utterance: Can you add synonym of `{ExistingSlotValue}`?

Intent: `TakeSynonymValue`
Utterance: set it as `{NewSynonymValue}`

> `ExistingSlotValue` is a custom slot of which values you can already
>   define based on all the `IOT` slots values you have.
>
> `NewSynonymValue` is of type `AMAZON.SearchQuery`

After this, you need to update interaction model based on the above responses you get in your handler functions.

You can take use of 'Alexa Skill Management API' `(SMAPI)`.
More on that here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-operations.html

You can get current interaction model:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-operations.html#get-interaction-model

Then update this interaction model with the modifications of adding `{NewSynonymValue}` to the synonyms of `{ExistingSlotValue}`: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/interaction-model-operations.html#update-interaction-model

After that, you need to publish your skill, yes, again with `SMAPI`:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-certification-operations.html#request

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, thank's for your answer! I'm using an external https endpoint API, you need to be logged with amazon on your skill account linking to use SM API or can i use a token that i generated from my API OAuth to communicate between Alexa and my API. Thanks by advance :)

Comment: Temporary solution would be to store `refresh token` and `access token` in an environment variable (if you are using lambda function you are able to change that easily). Every time access token expires (which you can know based on status code returned while accessing SMAPI), you need to use refresh token to fetch new access token. https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/refresh-token.html

Comment: And if your refresh token expires (which has a fairly longer expiry time than access token), you can request it using `Login with Amazon` and change the respective environment variable.

Comment: Thanks one more time for the helpfull answer, There is ApiAccessToken on Json Input, maybe could work. When you send request to SMAPI you send a header with token like this ? "Authorization: token"

Comment: @AkshayMilmile after a skill is published you won't be able to add a synonym this way.

Comment: @CicilThomas so when SMAPI will be helpfull for ? Thank's :)

Comment: @Nearyuk to answer your question, you need to send access Token in header like this: `'Authorization': {accessToken}`

Comment: @CicilThomas yes you are right, synonyms added won't be reflected unless skill is published again. Thank you for pointing that out. @Nearyuk you have to use `SMAPI` again to publish the skill: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-certification-operations.html#request